# Обработка произвольного название метода

Tags: c#, mvc, .net-core

Не знаю как правильно объяснить, суть вот в чем.

к примеру:

```
public class HomeController: Controller 
{

  public IActionResult Index() {
    return View();
  }


public IActionResult Test() {
    return View();
  }
 }
```

Я могу вызвать http://blabla.gg/home/test

т.е. делать вызовы по заранее определенному методу. Но я хочу делать произвольные вызовы и обрабатывать их.

В общем я хочу вызывать страницы с параметрами не так:

http://blabla.gg/home/test?ff=10

а вот так

[http://blabla.gg/home/test/произольное_название](http://blabla.gg/home/test/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 3):

Получилось благодаря Igor.

Добавляем маршрут в файл startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HomeRoute",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=test}/{arbitrary}/{id?}");

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

});
```

в самом контроллере добавляем

```
public IActionResult Test(string arbitrary, иные получаемые параметры) {
  return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes

...
Route route = routes.MapRoute(
  "RouteHomeTest", // Route name
  "Home/Test/{arbitrary}", // URL structure
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Test", arbitrary = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.Insert(0, route);

public IActionResult Test(string arbitrary) {
  return View();
}
```

Comment: У меня AspNetCore и там все это выглядит иначе. Вот так пишется маршруты routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); Я вот не пойму как переделать. В вашем варианте ругается на UrlParameter - не знает что это

Comment: Примерно разобрался